# Using nested $http.get calls in Angular JS sequentially

Tags: angularjs, http, scope, http-get

I have this situation where two $http.get calls are nested.I get result from the first call and then iterating over this first result and passing this to another $http.get call and in the end I amtrying to make whole thing as ab array of objects.I am finding that ,this whole is not happening in sequence.Could someone help me out?

```
  $scope.populateData = function()
      {
         $scope.infoWithStatus = [];

          $http.get("commonAppGet.jsp?sqlStr=select name from test where title_id=1").then(function(resp){
                  $scope.names = resp.data.d;
                  for(var i=0;$scope.names.length;i++){
                      infoObject= {};
                      var c1=0;c2=0; c3=0;c4=0;c5=0;
                      $scope.spocName = $scope.names[i].name;
                      infoObject.name=$scope.spocName;
                                $http.get("commonAppGet.jsp?sqlStr=select a.status as status from test1 where name='"+$scope.spocName+"'").then(function(resp){

                                   $scope.statusValues = resp.data.d;
                                    for(var i=0;i<$scope.statusValues.length;i++)
                                      {
                                          if($scope.statusValues[i].status==0)
                                            c1++;
                                          if($scope.statusValues[i].status==1)
                                              c2++;
                                          //some code for c3,c4,c5                    

                                       }
                                       infoObject.count1=c1;
                                       infoObject.count2=c2;                                                             
                                       infoObject.count3=c3;
                                       infoObject.count4=c4;
                                       infoObject.count5=c5;

                                });
                             $scope.infoWithStatus.push(infoObject); 
                       }
         });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be you

I saw that you missing `i < $scope.names.length` in the first promise

```
$scope.populateData = function()
    {
        $scope.infoWithStatus = [];
        var c1=0;c2=0; c3=0;c4=0;c5=0;
        $http.get("commonAppGet.jsp?sqlStr=select name from test where title_id=1").then(function(resp){
            $scope.names = resp.data.d;
            var listPromise = [];
            for(var i=0;i < $scope.names.length;i++){
                infoObject= {};
                $scope.spocName = $scope.names[i].name;
                infoObject.name=$scope.spocName;
                listPromise.push($http.get("commonAppGet.jsp?sqlStr=select a.status as status from test1 where name='"+$scope.spocName+"'"));
                $scope.infoWithStatus.push(infoObject); 
            }
            return Promise.all(listPromise);
        }).then(function(resp){
            for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                $scope.statusValues = resp[i].data.d;
                for(var i=0;i<$scope.statusValues.length;i++)
                {
                    if($scope.statusValues[i].status==0)
                    c1++;
                    if($scope.statusValues[i].status==1)
                        c2++;
                    //some code for c3,c4,c5                    

                }
                infoObject.count1=c1;
                infoObject.count2=c2;                                                             
                infoObject.count3=c3;
                infoObject.count4=c4;
                infoObject.count5=c5;
            }
        });
 }
```